# Getkey() in google app engine returns id

Tags: java, google-app-engine

My datastore table is named document and has is structured in the following matter:
Key, Write Ops, ID/Name, html, name. 
Sample data is:

```
Key: aglub19hcHBfaWRyDgsSCGRvY3VtZW50GAEM 
Write Ops:6
ID/Name:1
html:"<div>something</div>
name: "Untitled name"
```

Where the first three columns are created by Google App Engine. I fetch the entities from datastore with the code below:

```
int PAGE_SIZE = 20;
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
PreparedQuery queryString = datastore.prepare(new Query("document"));
int rowCount = queryString.countEntities();
int offset = 0;
//fetch results from datastore based on offset and page size
FetchOptions fetchOptions = FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(PAGE_SIZE);
QueryResultList<Entity> results = queryString.asQueryResultList(fetchOptions .offset(offset));
```

A problem occurs when I try to retreive the Key column from entity with .getKey() method.
Instead of returning the random string from column Key it returns document("1). Is there a way to get Keys from the results array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is not a "random string". It's a string encoding of the Key object.

I use the Python API rather than the Java one, but in Python you can simply call `str()` on the Key instance to get the encoded version. In Java you might be able to use `key.toString()`, or you may need to serialize it in some way.

Comment: key.toString() still returns the entity name with id integer. getKey() method should return the guid of the entity but for some strange reason is returning the kind and id combined.

Comment: Because as I say, that *is* what the "guid" is. It's not a guid, it's the serialization of kind+id (actually, the entire path, if your entity has parents they will be part of the key path too). You just need to serialize it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. As you said I just serialized it with this: KeyFactory.createKeyString("document", entity.getKey().getId()).